# Both WiFi and Ethernet don't work

Tags: wifi

I recently tried to dual boot Elementary OS with Windows 7. I can see WiFi networks but when I try and connect to them, it asks for the password then tries to connect. After a while it stops and asks me the password again. I'm using a TP-LINK TL-WN881ND Wireless Adapter. Whenever I try to connect to the internet via Ethernet it also doesn't work. It tries to connect me to the network and then disconnects. This is the output from sudo lshw -C network. Thanks for all your help in advance

```
elementary@elementary:~$ sudo lshw -C network
 *-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 01
   serial: e8:94:f6:fb:2b:ff
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.19.0-39-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:32 memory:fe800000-fe80ffff
 *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 06
   serial: 74:d4:35:99:77:fd
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:29 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fe700000-fe700fff memory:d0000000-d0003fff
elementary@elementary:~$
```

Comment: Post the result of `iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|cipher'` thanks